# Otimizar a colisão entre as partículas

Tags: c++, qt, detecção-de-colisão

Preciso otimizar ao máximo o algoritmo que faz a colisão entre as partículas, tem algo que possa ser feito para isso? E também pretendo adicionar uma imagem de background, é possível?

Segue código canvas.cpp:

```
canvas::canvas(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
m_particulas.resize(20);

int n = m_particulas.size();
for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i)
{
    m_particulas[i].init();
}

startTimer(10);
}

void canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
(void) event;

QPainter painter(this);
painter.setWindow(0,0,1000,1000);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 5, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::darkCyan, Qt::SolidPattern));

int n = m_particulas.size();
for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i)
{
    double x = m_particulas[i].x();
    double y = m_particulas[i].y();
    double L = m_particulas[i].r();
    painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(x, y), L, L);
}
}

void canvas::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
(void) event;

int n = m_particulas.size();

for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i)
{
    m_particulas[i].andar();
    Particula &pi = m_particulas[i];

    for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j)
    {
        if (i == j) continue;

        Particula &pj = m_particulas[j];

        if (pi.testa_colisao(pj))
        {
            pi.calcula_colisao(pj);
        }
    }
pi.andar();
}
update();
}
```

particulas.cpp:

```
Particula::Particula()
{

}

void Particula::init()
{
m_r = 20;

m_x = 900.0*rand()/RAND_MAX + 50;
m_y = 900.0*rand()/RAND_MAX + 50;

m_vx = 2.0 * rand()/RAND_MAX - 1;
m_vy = 2.0 * rand()/RAND_MAX - 1;

double norma = sqrt(m_vx*m_vx + m_vy*m_vy);
m_vx /= norma;
m_vy /= norma;

}

void Particula::normaliza(double &vx, double &vy)
{
double norma = sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy);
if (norma > 0)
{
    vx /= norma;
    vy /= norma;
}
}

bool Particula::testa_colisao (Particula &p)
{
    double dx = x() - p.x();
    double dy = y() - p.y();
    double dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    return dist <= r() + p.r();
}

void Particula::calcula_colisao(Particula &p)
{
    double vx = p.x() - x();
    double vy = p.y() - y();
    normaliza(vx,vy);

    p.m_vx += vx;
    p.m_vy += vy;
    normaliza(p.m_vx,p.m_vy);

    m_vx -= vx;
    m_vy -= vy;
    normaliza(m_vx, m_vy);

    while (testa_colisao(p))
    {
        andar();
        p.andar();
    }
}

double Particula::x() const
{
return m_x;
}

double Particula::y() const
{
return m_y;
}

double Particula::r() const
{
return m_r;
}

void Particula::andar()
{
m_x += m_vx;
m_y += m_vy;

if(m_x > 1000-m_r) m_vx *= -1; //inferior - multiplicado por -1 para inverter a direção...
if(m_y > 1000-m_r) m_vy *= -1; //direita
if(m_x < 0+m_r) m_vx *= -1; //esquerda
if(m_y < 0+m_r) m_vy *= -1; //superior
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para uma otimização simples que não demande muita mudança no código, eu tenho três sugestões:

1. Você está testando todas as partículas contra todas as outras duas vezes (i.e. `i` de `[0,n]` vs `j` de `[0,n]`). Teste-as apenas uma vez:

   ```
   for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i)
   {
       m_particulas[i].andar();
       Particula &pi = m_particulas[i];

       for(int j = i+1 ; j < n ; ++j)
       {
           //if (i == j) continue;

           Particula &pj = m_particulas[j];
   ```

   Para isso ser possível, não faça a partícula andar **depois** de testar pela colisão. Em vez disso, mova **todas** as partículas primeiro, depois comece os testes (P.S. por que você está movendo cada partícula duas vezes?):

   ```
   // Primeiro move
   for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
       m_particulas[i].andar();

   // Depois testa
   for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; ++i)
   {
       Particula &pi = m_particulas[i];

       for(int j = i+1 ; j < n ; ++j) ...
   ```
2. O cálculo da raiz quadrada é muito mais lento que a multiplicação. Eleve a equação da distância inteira ao quadrado de modo a evitar esse cálculo:

   ```
   bool Particula::testa_colisao (Particula &p)
   {
       double dx = x() - p.x();
       double dy = y() - p.y();
       double dist2 = dx*dx + dy*dy;
       double somaRaios = r() + p.r()
       return dist2 <= somaRaios * somaRaios;
   }
   ```
3. No `calcula_colisao`, faça a partícula andar pelo menos uma vez antes de testar *de novo* se há colisões (pois da primeira vez que executar, sempre retornará `true`):

   ```
   ...
   normaliza(m_vx, m_vy);

   do
   {
       andar();
       p.andar();
   } while (testa_colisao(p));
   ```

Isso deve evitar todo trabalho desnecessário no código atual. Com base nisso, podemos passar pras otimizações mais complexas, que envolvem refatorar o programa como um todo. [Essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2544431/520779) dá algumas sugestões promissoras:

1. Divida seu espaço em áreas menores, e faça o cálculo separadamente para cada uma dessas áreas. Por exemplo, se seu cenário é um quadrado de `100x100`, crie 9 quadrados de `40x40` (com alguma interseção entre os quadrados, de modo que uma partícula muito perto da fronteira não deixe de ser testada contra o quadrado adjacente) e coloque cada partícula em um ou mais quadrados. Atualize isso a cada movimento (deve ser rápido, pois é só uma questão de comparar posições `x` e `y` - e se o número de sub-áreas for grande, pode-se fazer uma busca binária). Ao testar por colisões, considere somente as partículas que estão no mesmo quadrado.

   - Bônus: esse é um bom candidato para paralelização - crie um processo/thread separado para lidar com cada quadrado. Apenas tome cuidado para o *overhead* da gestão da concorrência não anular o benefício, essa técnica só vale a pena se o número de partículas for bastante grande.
2. Em vez de buscar por colisões a cada quadro da simulação, guarde em outra estrutura de dados as distâncias entre cada par de partículas dividido pela soma de suas velocidades. Esse valor corresponde ao número mínimo de quadros necessário para que *exista uma chance* dessas partículas colidirem. Se na hora de testar pela colisão esse valor for maior ou igual a `1`, decremente-o e não faça o teste - pois com certeza retornará falso. Se for menor, faça o teste e atualize a previsão de colisão (que pode ter aumentado, diminuido, ou permanecido a mesma, dependendo das direções do movimento).

   - Nota: se seus quadros não têm duração fixa, adaptações podem ser necessárias.

   Toda vez que uma partícula colidir com qualquer outra, sua velocidade pode aumentar. Você *poderia* recalcular essa matriz de previsões inteira [para essa partícula] sempre que isso acontecesse, mas imagino que seria por demais custoso. Uma aproximação razoável poderia ser simplesmente reduzir todos os valores proporcionalmente (ex.: a velocidade aumentou de `2` pra `3`, divida todas as previsões de colisão em `1.5`).

Essas técnicas podem ser combinadas (i.e. divida seu espaço em áreas menores, e faça a matriz de previsões para cada sub-área), e há [outras mais sofisticadas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangula%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Delaunay) a se considerar. Apenas tome o cuidado de pesar as vantagens/desvantagens de cada uma delas segundo o seu caso particular. Exemplos:

- Se há muitas partículas em relação ao espaço, de modo que as colisões serão frequentes e localizadas, a estratégia 1 é mais interessante e a 2 desnecessária; divida seu espaço em bastantes sub-áreas, pois será raro uma partícula mover-se de uma área pra outra.
- Se há poucas partículas em relação ao espaço, e elas se movem bastante rápido, a estratégia 1 é inútil (pois toda hora uma partícula mudará de sub-área) e a 2 mais interessante; mantenha a matriz de previsões ordenada, de modo que você não precise percorrê-la toda ao testar cada partícula.
- Outros casos particulares vão ter diferentes impactos na melhor estratégia.